# Performing raster calculations with more than two bands in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal

We need to perform raster calculations using more than two bands in PostGIS.  At the moment, ST_MapAlgebra has a two-band form but doesn't support more than that.

I'm open to any solution others would like to offer, but am currently favoring writing a custom plpython function that might be called as follows

```sql
SELECT
    ST_FromGDALRaster(
        some_custom_function(
            ST_AsGDALRaster(
                some_raster_column,
                'GTiff'
            )
        )
    ) new_raster_column
FROM some_table
```

where the custom function accepts and returns a bytea PostgreSQL datatype.  Inside the function I am able to import gdal and use following

```
vsipath = '/vsimem/buffer'
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vsipath, gdal_rast)
rast = gdal.Open(vsipath)
```

gdal_rast above is the parameter being passed into the custom function resulting from the ST_AsGDALRaster function in the select clause.  From there, I can turn the bands into numpy arrays and process as desired.

My problem comes in returning the processed raster back from the custom function to the database.  I have tried the MEM driver to create an in-memory raster, but when I return that raster to the ST_FromGDALRaster function from the custom function I receive this error:

```
ERROR: RASTER_fromGDALRaster: Could not open bytea with GDAL.
Check that the bytea is of a GDAL supported format
```

Can the plpython function approach be salvaged?  Or is there a better solution that avoids plpython altogether?

Comment: If you functions are linear, can you not call ST_MapAlgebra twice to combine 3 rasters. I realize that this does not directly answer the question.

Comment: That is looking like the only solution that will work, I will try that approach.

Comment: Our data scientist just let me know that the functions are unfortunately non-linear so nesting ST_MapAlgebra functions won't work.  Please let me know if there are other ideas out there.

Comment: Are you sure postgis only supports 2 bands? The documentation seems to indicate otherwise.  http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html

Comment: I was looking at the expression version of ST_MapAlgebra, looks like the rastbandarg of the callback version will meet our needs.  Missed that, thanks for calling it to my attention!

Answer (score 1):

*tilt* pointed out in the comments above that the rastbandarg version of ST_MapAlgebra's callback form accepts more than two raster bands.  This approach solves the problem.