# Is it possible to do raster calculations with ST_Union (PostGIS)?

Tags: postgis, gdal, raster-calculator

I would like to perform raster calculations in PostGIS. (A change detection should be performed, for this purpose every pixel of different raster is accessed and it is checked if the pixel values have changed over the time period).

Which PostGIS function should be used best for this? I thought `ST_MapAlgebra` would be the best choice, but in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218276/st-mapalgebra-and-combination-of-four-rasters) it was written that `ST_Union` is better suited for this purpose, even if simple calculations are to be performed.

So what function should be used and how would you implement the change detection. (The Analysis will be similar to this GDAL Calculation, where A,B,C,D,E are five different bands.  `(logical_and(A-B, B-A) != 0) * 1 + (logical_and(B-C, C-B) != 0) * 1 + (logical_and(C-D,D-C) != 0 )* 1 + (logical_and(D-E,E-D) != 0) * 1`

Edit: Furthermore can you do calculations with ST_MapAlgebra with more than two bands?

Comment: Here's the answer for the last question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176796/performing-raster-calculations-with-more-than-two-bands-in-postgis 
So I guess ST_MapAlgebra will be probably the right function to use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When more complicated calculations are performed as returning the average or maximum value of multiple grids, ST_MapAlgebra should be used and not [ST_Union](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html).

A tutorial which shows a better example than the official documentation of [of ST_MapAlgebra at the PostGIS page](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html) can be found [here](https://nronnei.github.io/blog/2017/03/random-map-algebra-callback-in-postgis-pt2/). It also explains how to initialize the callback function which is needed when working with more than two grids.